# Any latest development is happening on releasing a stable build for Wix 3.14 or Wix 4.0

Tags: wix, wix3.11, wix4

There is an existing issue with Wix SQL extension not working with TLS1.2 enabled (https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5543).We would like to consume this fix as most of our installation environment is shifting to TLS 1.2.The issue seems to be fixed and available in Wix 3.14 Dev builds but we would like to use RTM build for our need. So any idea on when is the next RTM release for Wix Toolset.

Answer (score 2):

There may never be an "RTM" build of WiX v3.14. From http://www.joyofsetup.com/2018/05/19/wix-v314-details-about-wix-pi/:

> The purpose of WiX v3.14 is to help you get to WiX v4.0, so it’s a release you use briefly before moving on to WiX v4.0, not adopt for the long term.

If there is a build we mark "stable," it will come out around the same time as WiX v4, so it serves its purpose to help migrate to WiX v4.

WiX v4 will enter alpha this summer.

Answer (score 1):

WiX 3.14 release has been the topic for the past few wix-devs online meetings.  I think there was a meeting today but the invite was messed up and don't see it posted on the firegiant blog yet.

http://lists.wixtoolset.org/pipermail/wix-devs-wixtoolset.org/2019-June/001373.html
https://www.firegiant.com/blog/

Short version is 3.14 is really close. I dev build containing VS2019 support was released three weeks ago:

https://wixtoolset.org/releases/development/

WiX 4.0 is years away to be honest.  I wouldn't worry about it at all right now.  In fact the WiX v4 templates were recently removed from Votive (Visual Studio Extension)  so that should give you an idea how far out it is.